# Prevent VSCode from putting stream methods after eachother for Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, formatting, java-stream

The Java extension for Visual Studio Code has some annoying formatting when putting multiple methods after each other. It likes to format my code like this.

```java
Item item = items.stream().filter(m -> m.getItemName() == itemName).findFirst().orElse(Item.DEFAULT);
```

How can I make the extension format it like this:

```java
Item item = items.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getItemName() == itemName)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(Item.DEFAULT);
```

or like this:

```java
Item item = items.stream()
                 .filter(m -> m.getItemName() == itemName)
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(Item.DEFAULT);
```

I can't find the setting from the [Formatter settings GitHub wiki page](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Formatter-settings) and the provided templates.

Comment: which plugin do you exactly mean?

Comment: @sudipn [Java Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) (from the [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack))

Comment: The settings you can find File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extension -> Java configuration. In this section, you have *Format Settings url* (java.format.settings.url). Or alternatively, you can search for `java.format.settings.url` in the setting's search bar.